# remove onclick in a TD tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a TD tag in my HTML as follows

```
<TD onclick="Javascript:OpenModal(....);.."></TD>
```

I need to write something in Javascript to remove the above onclick event dynamically
How do I do that? I tried following ways:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].onmousedown = null;
document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].removeAttribute = "onclick"
document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].removenamedAttribute("onclick")
```

I also tried disabling the whole table and it worked but I dont want to disable (because it becomes grey). Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute) is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removeAttribute("onclick") is somehow not working for me and i do not know why .I am totally new to these scripting languages. But some how I made it to work by disabling that particular single cell.. since it did not have any data other than onclik event it did not matter me by disabling it. Here is my psuedocode

var table = document.getElementById("table_id");

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

if (j == 7) { row.cells[j].disabled = true; }

}

}

i am trying to improve the above code to make it dynamic..let's see how it goes..

Answer (score 3):

You're missing this

> **Syntax:** [`element.removeAttribute(attrName);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.removeAttribute)

```
document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].removeAttribute("onclick");
```

Comment: I mean..I was still able to click and it is trying to call the event handler

Comment: @AVSSM: What's `x`?  Where is this line being called?

Comment: I think it's better to loop through over all the `<td>` elements, sounds like the OP does not know which specific cell to disable.

Comment: @AVSSM:- Please check if you are disabling the correct cell and what is **x** :)

Comment: He's probably still _assigning_ to `removeAttribute` like he is in his original code.

Comment: @AVSSM You should create a fiddle, it seems you're having problem in other part of the code.

Comment: @AVSSM:- Could you please share a JSFIDDLE as this must work for you. You might be doing something wrong in other part of your code!!!

Comment: @Rahul    I was actually looping through the TD's something like below: while (x < document.getElementsByTagName("TD").length) { document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].removeAttribute("onclick"); x++; }

Comment: @AVSSM: You *are* setting `var x = 0;` before that loop, right?

Comment: @AVSSM:- That is why we are asking you to share a JSFIDDLE or your code. As there is surely something wrong in your code!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[x].removeAttribute("onclick");
```